# Is it more efficient to call functions or fill control if statements with local variables rather than directly nesting a function call?

Tags: c++, local-variables

In C++, does it produce a faster executable if you supply the data to be compared within the brackets of an `if` statement as the implicit result of a nested function instead of a separate local variable?  In the same way, is it more efficient to provide an argument to a function as the result of a nested function called, again instead of a separate local variable?

What I mean is:

```
int comparison=0;
char *name=nullptr;

GetNameFromRegistry(queried_name);  //Unillustrated function that retrieves a name
                                    //entry from the Windows registry, dynamically
                                    //allocates a sufficiently-sized chunk of memory
                                    //to hold it and null-terminates the string.

comparison=strcmp(queried_name,"Fred");

if(comparison==0){
    MessageBox(NULL,
        "We have found Fred.",
        "Name Search", 
        MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
```

as opposed to:

```
char *queried_name=nullptr;

GetNameFromRegistry(queried_name);  //Unillustrated function that retrieves a name
                                    //entry from the Windows registry, dynamically
                                    //allocates sufficiently-sized chunk of memory
                                    //to hold it and null-terminates the string.


if(strcmp(queried_name, "Fred")==0){
    MessageBox(NULL,
        "We have found Fred.",
        "Name Search",
        MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
```

Another example:

```
CData gp_data;  //CData is a class that holds values, arrays and
                //volatile/non-volatilve data for a windows application, 
                //saving those non-volatile values to the registry to be
                //retrieved the next time it is launched.

SendMessage(dialog,
    WM_SETICON,
    reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(ICON_SMALL),
    reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(gp_data->Get_Small_Application_Icon()));
```

as opposed to:

```
HICON small_icon=0;
CData gp_data;  //CData is a class with holds values, arrays and volatile data for
                //a windows application, saving non-volatile values to the registry
                //to use the next time it is launched.

small_icon=gp_data->Get_Small_Application_Icon();

SendMessage(dialog,
    WM_SETICON,
    reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(ICON_SMALL),
    reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(small_icon));
```

Obviously in the first example, the first form requires an extra local variable be allocated from the stack, but I personally think it is easier to read/debug.

Again, in the second example an extra local variable is required, which once more I think is easier to read.  However, perhaps there are performance gains to be had from the first form that compensate for a loss in readability?

Comment: The example doesn't match the title or question.

Comment: Whatever is the most clear. In general, don't do work in an if statement though. For example, if a function `foo()` does work, then returns a `bool` indicating if the function was successful, don't say `if (foo()) { // do stuff }`

Comment: In the second example also a rvalue is required for the result of `strcmp`. Consequently, I don't see a performance distinction in the two paradigms.

Comment: You seem to be implying `if` is a function. It's not. Also, any marginally competent compiler will not put the `comparison` local variable on the stack, so your two examples will produce identical assembly. It really comes down to readability and maintainability.

Comment: Depending on the compiler optimization, the local variable could end up in a register instead of being allocated from the stack.

Comment: Obviously my mistake chris - what is the matter between the brackets of an `if` statement officially called? I will correct accordingly.

Comment: I have heavily edited both the question title, the examples inside the question text and the tags to hopefully provoke fact-based answers instead of opinions.  Although, in my opinion I was getting mainly fact-based answers already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the second one better. The new variable adds no more semantic to the code. It is just a dummy variable. Its name, comparission, says nothing. Perhaps you could have written:

```
bool is_specific_name = strcmp(name,"Specific Name") == 0;

if (is_specific_name) {
...
}
```

At least now the variable tells the reader something. Maybe someone unfamiliar with strcmp would appreciate it. Although, if the audience of your code are people familiar with C, then they'd probably know all about strcmp and they would probably appreciate the shorter code.

However, if we are writing C++, why are we using strcmp and not string comparison? Why use C's char array? Certanly

```
if (name == "Specific Name") {
...
}
```

would be the most semantic of all expressions. In that case the extra variable seems quite unecessary.

As for performance, an optimizing compiler should generate the same code for both constructions, given that you don't use the variable anywhere else.

Comment: MANY thanks Rafael!!!  It is precisely for gems of information like this that I thought I would join this forum - I did not know you could do direct string comparison!  I thought such a statement would merely compare the address of the pieces of memory where the null-terminated strings were stored. Perhaps it is a feature that has been added since I learned the basics of the language at my local technical college.

Comment: Take care with string comparisons, though. If name is a std::string, then the == will do what you want. Otherwise, if it's a char*, it will perform a pointer comparison. I questioned the use of strcmp because, if you're using C++, you're probably better off using string rather than char*.

Comment: The problem I find with either std::string or any of the other class-encapsulated string types is they are tricky to interface with the windows api.  By the time you have finished getting a pointer to their core char array you might have as well used a null-terminated string from the start.

Comment: I find using std::string so much better than handling char* that, unless it's a very small program, I'd write a thin wrapper around C functions I'm calling. In case of winapi, probably there are also good abstraction layers already implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Smart compilers might generate same binary code for both styles. So you can do some compilation and disassembling to confirm it, if you are really intrested.